# Jest coverage says my conditional isn't being covered, but it's using that code

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm using node and testing with jest.

I have a function like this:

```
12 function replace(obj, key, data) {
13   if (!data) {
14     return;
15   }
16
17   if (!obj[key]) {
18     obj[key] = {}; 
19   }
20
21   obj[key] = deepmerge(obj[key], data);
22 }
```

and here's what I'm doing to test it:

```
test('my test', () => {
  let obj = { a: 1 };

  expect(obj.b).not.toBeDefined();
  replace(obj, 'b', {foo:"bar"});
  expect(obj.b.foo).toBe("bar");
});
```

The test passes, of course.  But no matter what I do, my test coverage says line 17 is not covered.  I could leave it, but out of curiosity, I would like to figure out *why* its not being considered covered (and/or how I could fix it).  Any insights?

Comment: what is the `a` you are passing as first arg of `replace`, is it `obj.a` or `obj`

Comment: @cmgchess that 'a' was just a typo (fixed now).  I finally figured out the issue -- I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a fairly subtle problem.

Line 17 was testing what happens if the key doesn't exist in `obj`.  It turns out that *all* my tests were hitting that line, which meant that the *implicit else* (when `key` *does* exist in `obj`) was never getting tested.

Jest was warning that the *other* branch of the `if(...)` wasn't being tested (the implicit else).  But, of course, since it's implicit, it couldn't point to a line number.  It had to point to the line that created the implicit else.

The fix was simply to test both the `if` condition and its alternative `else`.